# Safari infinite translateX animation flickers on loop

Tags: css

I have this code

```
.wave {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 1920px * 2;
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: 1920px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: wave 3s linear infinite;
  @keyframes wave {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
      // left: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(-1920px);
      // left: -1920px;
    }
  }
}
```

which should loop seamlessly creating a continuous wave motion. Unfortunately, in safari, it flickers on every loop. I have tried all the `-webkit` stuff and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`, but no luck

If I remove `transform: translateX(...)` and animate `left` instead, the flickering disappears, but I want to use `transform` for perfomance reasons

**I have created this [simple example here](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/zYzZWzw?editors=0100)**

You can see the flicker on every loop (3s) in safari. Works fine in chrome

Comment: Have you found any solution for that? I also faced this issue recently and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Any solution? Same issue.

Comment: I managed to avoid this issue by reducing the size of my animated content. Likely related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759785/2612679)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to img or picture element will do the trick

Comment: Please provide an example with working code if possible and explain why your solution works.   Some kind of codepen or fiddle or the built-in SO sandbox, is preferred as well.  Basically, if your solution works, then sandbox it, and explain.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Safari appears to have trouble with rendering images when an animation restarts.

Just to make this clear, the issue is specifically with images not with the animation. So we need to use hardware acceleration on the element that displays the image no matter if it's the one being animated or just a child of the animated element.

For this question the animated element and the image-displaying element are the same. That's why we solve the issue by editing all keyframes to either use `translate3d(x, 0, 0)` instead of `translateX(x)` or we can also just add `translateZ(0)` before or after `translateX(x)`.

```
@keyframes wave {
0% {
  transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
}
100% {
  transform: translateX(-1920px) translateZ(0);
}
```

}

However some people might run into an issue, whenever an animated element has an image as its child. So something like this: (assume the "articleWheel" element has an animation that endlessly scrolls through)

```
<div class="articleWheel">
   <figure>
      <img class="articleImg" src="article1.jpg" width="500" height="200" />
      <figcaption>
         Soap
      </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
      <img class="articleImg" src="article2.jpg" width="500" height="200" />
      <figcaption>
         Lotion
      </figcaption>
   </figure>
</div>
```

In this case, make sure that you apply hardware acceleration onto the images specifically by doing something like this:

```
.articleImg {
   transform: translateZ(0);
}
```